# Set widget in center in QDesigner

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator, qt-designer

Is it possible to set widget in center of dialog or windows in QDesigner, say I have a widget contain 3 line edits and labels and I want to set this widget in center of window.

Answer (score 36):

In latest Qt Designer, right-click a widget in the *Object Inspector* and choose your preference under *Layout Alignment*.

[image: Layout Alignment]

Comment: I believe this only works QT 4.8+. The answer by @Seba will cover earlier qt versions. If you use the 'Layout Alignment' and try to compiler with earlier versions of qt uic will error.

Comment: For versions which support this answer, the "in the ***Object Inspector"*** bit is key. If you right-click on the item in the design view, the Layout Alignment option may not appear.

Answer (score 6):

It should be quite simple:

1. Insert horizontal spacer
2. Set Horizontal layout
3. Insert Vertical layout
4. Insert another horizontal spacer
5. Add Vertical spacer to Horizontal spacer (drag to widget tree)
6. Add your widgets .... labels, textedits
7. Add another vertical sapcer to Horizontal space

Works in my QtCreator, should also in Your Designer :)

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Add a layout to your windows and add the widgets in the layout. Then you can set the position policy in the properties panel of the [layout](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlayout.html#setAlignment-2).

Comment: I don't understand you well, witch layout I have to use.

Comment: In your case, since you only have one widget to add to the window, you can use any layout. In Designer Do this: Add the widget in the windows then click on one button layout on the top. Default behavior is to center widget inside the layout.

Comment: I think I get it, I put two verticalSpacer up and under my widget, and two horizontalSpacer right and left the widget then I select all of theme and I apply Grid layout, finally I apply grid layout on tab in my case or dialog, window in your case.